# Dual boot fail, Windows 7 doesnt Load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

After installing Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 7, I could not at first boot into either Ubuntu or Windows 7.

I then ran boot-repair from a live USB and restarted. After this, I was able to boot into Ubuntu 14.04. But Windows 7 still refuses to boot.

Grub shows the entry for booting Windows, but after selecting Windows, I am presented with the Windows screen, followed by a quick flash of a blue screen, then dumped back into grub.

Some additional info:
 When I ran boot-repair, it mentioned that my **NTFS was now SFS**, and it had an LDM blocker.

Help?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried changing boot order in BIOS so Windows is first?  It should boot directly to Windows and see if the problem persists.  Also edit your question, add the list of your partitions (run `sudo parted --list`). It's hard to help someone without information provided..That SFS is very strange though...

Comment: Microsoft proprietary dynamic partitions are shown as SFS with fdisk. Microsoft recommends backup, erase drive, and reinstall. But third party Windows tools can convert from SFS to basic if you do not have more than 4 primary partitions total. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html

Answer (score 1):

okay after much deliberation, i decided to re-install windx from recovery disks and install ubuntu. this did it for me, my dynamic disks reverted back to basic, result! i then re-installed ubuntu 14.04 lts from live install off usb. i had to delete create my partitions once again in windows disk manager, had to delete my recovery partition as only four disks are recognized for my mbr disk array then re-installed ubuntu working!